# O que a tag <aside> faz em HTML?

Tags: html, html5

Gostaria de saber qual a função da tag `<aside>` e saber se existe alguma semelhança com a tag `<nav>`, pois no código que estou fazendo troquei `aside` por `nav` e não houve mudanças.

Answer (score 3):

`aside` é uma [tag semântica](https://www.devmedia.com.br/html-semantico-conheca-os-elementos-semanticos-da-html5/38065) introduzida no HTML5. Ou seja, ela tem por objetivo descrever melhor o significado do seu conteúdo, tanto para browsers, quanto para programadores.

No caso da tag `aside` ([referência](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/HTML/Element/aside)):

> O elemento HTML  representa uma seção de uma página que
>   consiste de conteúdo que é tangencialmente relacionado ao conteúdo do
>   seu entorno, que poderia ser considerado separado do conteúdo. Essas
>   seções são, muitas vezes, representadas como barras laterais.

A imagem abaixo ilustra onde a tag `aside` deve ser utilizada em documentos HTML:

[image: Uso da tag aside]

Logo, se o conteúdo que está dentro da sua tag `aside` não está lateralizado em sua página, muito provavelmente você não deve usar ela.

Já a tag `nav` é utilizada para indiciar um elemento de navegação. Geralmente ela engloba um conjunto de links. Na imagem acima a tag `nav` é utilizada abaixo do `header` da página, local muito utilizado para abrigar menus de navegação.

Quando você troca `aside` por `nav`, você está deixando de indicar para o navegador que o conteúdo em questão é um conteúdo lateral e passando a indicar que tal conteúdo é um conteúdo de navegação. Ou seja: a mudança é **semântica** (significado) e não visual.

Answer (score 0):

**O que é o elemento ?**

O elemento HTML  representa uma seção de uma página que consiste de conteúdo que é tangencialmente relacionado ao conteúdo do seu entorno, que poderia ser considerado separado do conteúdo.

Essas seções são, muitas vezes, representadas como barras laterais. Elas muitas vezes contem explicações laterais, como a definição de um glossário; conteúdo vagamente relacionado, como avisos; a biografia do autor; ou, em aplicações web, informações de perfil ou links de blogs relacionados.

**Exemplo de uso**

```html
<p>My family and I visited The Epcot center this summer.</p>

<aside>
  <h4>Epcot Center</h4>
  <p>The Epcot Center is a theme park in Disney World, Florida.</p>
</aside>
```

**Compatibilidade**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

link de onde tirei [imagens](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/HTML/Element/aside) e referencia